# How to pass an image between view controllers without using segue

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm getting an **error** :

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)

while trying to pass the image that is selected from Photo library, to the other view controller.

Source ViewController -

```
@IBAction func myButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) 
   {
        let secondVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondVC") as! secondVC
        secondVC.passedVName = VNameTextField.text!
        secondVC.passedCcName = DropTextBox.text!
        secondVC.passedVImage = VImageView.image! 
        navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVC, animated: true)

    }
```

Destination ViewController -

```
 class secondVC: UIViewController 
    {
        @IBOutlet weak var DisplayPassedImage: UIImageView!
        @IBOutlet weak var ccNameDisplayLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var VNameDisplayLabel: UILabel!
        var passedVName = ""
        var passedCcName = ""
        var passedVImage = UIImage() 
        override func viewDidLoad() 
            {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            VNameDisplayLabel.text = passedVName
            ccNameDisplayLabel.text = passedCcName
            DisplayPassedImage.image = passedVImage // Error- Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP,subcode=0x0)
            }
    }
```

**Note:** 'PassedVName' and 'passedCcName' data are successfully passed to destination ViewController. if I try to pass 'passedVImage',I get an error.

Comment: not an answer, just a suggestion: don't start with capital letter in property and variable names. VImageView.image reads like image is class property of VImageView class. It makes reading code much harder, stick to the common style for given language

Comment: Why Do you want to pass Image ?

If you have image then pass image name to anotherViewController 

Or If You dont have image (If you have image URL)

Then Pass Image Path to anotherViewController

Comment: Double check to make sure your `@IBOutlet` for `DisplayPassedImage` is connected in your Storyboard.

Comment: Is this the complete error? I suspect it also says something like `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)`

Comment: Since the `image` property on `UIImageView` is optional, you could make the `passedVImage` optional like `var passedVImage: UIImage?` which will make you code safer and will alleviate the need of having to do `VImageView.image!` in the source viewcontroller when passing the value in. That could help the situation and you can more easily observe whether or not that image being passed is `nil` or not. It's unfortunate that you can't use initializer injection in storyboards still. Forces you into an unsafe situation more times than not

Comment: As per my understanding: When you are assigning  VImageView.image!  an image try to make copy of that image and then assign to it.

Comment: okey, will follow it @lope.. if there are such way, tell me how @ Vivek Gajbe.. checked it for sure @ vacawama..  That fatal error is also shown in the console @ shallowThought.. i tried making 'passedVImage' optional like var passedVImage: UIImage? . but it requires to declare the type like this 'UIImage?()' and it reports

Comment: var passedVImage = UIImage() does not declare type, it initializes property to new instance of UIImage object, what you want is "var passedVImage: UIImage?"

Comment: i have changed the declaration as you said 'var passedVImage: UIImage?' it reports the same error when i try to pass the image.  @lope and cjrieck

Comment: @KarthikeyanSk I wasn't trying to fix the error, I just pointed out things that were "wrong" with your code, hence just a comment and not an answer. I am not sure why you are getting that error, the code you posted should be working. Maybe you are doing something with the image somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NotificationCenter` to pass action/message to any viewController. Here you need to take `UIImage` object in `AppDelegate` (Means Globally) so you can pass it any where.

Ex.
1) You are in firstVC
2) In the firstVC choose the Image and add this image in the image object that you took in `AppDelegate`
3) Post your Notification in firstVC  that you want to pass action
4) Add Observe on your SecondVC
5) You can get image from `AppDelegate` object (Global object).

Otherwise you can use **Protocol**.

Answer (score 0):

In my limited experience with you should change `.jpg` to `.png`  image